# How to disable logging from the Marqo python client

Tags: python, marqo

The newest release of Marqo seems to have added additional logging to the Marqo python client. How do I turn this off?

```
>>> mq.index("new").add_documents([{"field1": "hello"}])
2023-01-27 14:27:33,178 logger:'marqo' INFO add_documents pre-processing: took 0.000s for 1 docs, for an average of 0.000s per doc.
2023-01-27 14:27:34,561 logger:'marqo' INFO add_documents roundtrip: took 1.383s to send 1 docs to Marqo (roundtrip, unbatched), for an average of 1.383s per doc.
2023-01-27 14:27:34,561 logger:'marqo' INFO add_documents Marqo index: took 1.087s for Marqo to process & index 1 docs (server unbatched), for an average of 1.087s per doc.
2023-01-27 14:27:34,561 logger:'marqo' INFO add_documents completed. total time taken: 1.385s.
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this to set the log level to warning. It should make the log messages disappear.

```
marqo.set_log_level('WARN')
```